# Gowebly - Can't find air and templ when creating and running a project

Tags: go, gowebly

I've began bootstrapping a Go project with [gowebly](https://gowebly.org/complete-user-guide/installation).

But after trying to create a project, I'm ran with the following issue:

```
failed to run action 'install project dependencies' in goroutine: can't execute command 'templ' with option '[generate]': exec: "templ": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Although I do see all files generated. If I try to run it using `gowebly run`, I get:

```
failed to run action 'install project dependencies' in goroutine: can't execute command 'air' with option '[generate]': exec: "air": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I've tried manually installing `templ`, and `air` through their respective sites, but this problem still persists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have Air tool and Templ package installed before proceeding:

1. Run `gowebly doctor`

[image: not installed air and templ]

2. If these are not shown, install each of them:
   2.1. [Templ](https://templ.guide/quick-start/installation):

```bash
go install github.com/a-h/templ/cmd/templ@latest
```

2.2 [Air](https://github.com/cosmtrek/air#via-go-install-recommended):

```bash
go install github.com/cosmtrek/air@latest
```

2.3 [Bun](https://bun.sh/docs/installation) (Look for more alternatives)

```
brew install oven-sh/bun/bun #
```

3. Run `gowebly doctor` again.

If still these show as `false`, then, you are likely experiencing some problems with your PATH and Go installation.

4. Add `$GOPATH/bin` to your Path (Linux and MacOS):
   (Temporary)

```
export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin
```

If using bash or zsh (Look for):

```
~/.bash_profile (bash)
~/.zshrc (zsh)
```

(These are generally on your root)

(If you're using Windows, follow this [tutorial](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html):

And then add:

```
export PATH="$(go env GOPATH)/bin:$PATH"
```

(Note the `:`. This will concat all the paths defined in the variable!)

Open it.

5. Run `gowebly doctor` again and you'll see the result:
   [image: gowebly true]
6. Now, delete all the files and run `gowebly create` again.
   (If you are still having issues. Try restarting your machine)